# Does PhantomJs supports constant(const) and let?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJs for unit testing angularJs app.

So my question is , Does PhantomJs supports constant(const) and let?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently supported.

Check this [thread](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14506) on the official github repo. It seem to appear [after version 2.5.0](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14506)